# jquery: using OR with .click()?

Tags: jquery, function, attributes, click

I need help trying to figure out how to use .click() function for two different attributes.

```
$('#prev').click(function() {}
```

and

```
$('#image').click(function() {}
```

So how would I do an OR statement if user clicks on #prev and #image without writing two identical scripts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('#prev, #image').click(function() {...});
```

or

```
function handleClick() {}
$('#prev').click(handleClick);
$('#image').click(handleClick);
```

Comment: Yep. @andrewliu, remember that for the most part jQuery uses CSS selectors. Actually still they use [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) if I recall correctly.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm going to choose this as the correct answer cause you were the first one to answer! ... wish I can choose multiple correct answers. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

You could:

```
$('#prev, #image').click(function() {});
```

or

```
function mine() {}
$('#prev').click(function() { mine(); });
$('#image').click(function() { mine(); });
```

Comment: The second example is wrong, it binds the result of the function instead of the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
$('#prev, #image').click(function() {...});
```